# Updating an ManyToMany field with Django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to set up this API so I can use a "PUT" to  update one/many "TAG"s on an item in the model "MOVIE". Tags is an M2M on MOVIE. I am posting on the PK of the item in movie.

My httpie work (returns a 200OK) but nothing gets created. When I post the whole JSON (using fetch) it just creates the TAG but no M2M relationship on MOVIE ([link](http://dpaste.com/0VCP53P)).

httpie

```
http -f PUT http://localhost:8000/api/Edit/3/ tag:='{"name": "TEST"}'
```

Models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=5000, blank=True)
    taglevel = models.IntegerField("Tag level", null=True, blank=True)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Whats happening?", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class Tag1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)

class EditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = Tag1Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
            model = Movie
            fields = ('title', 'tag', 'info', 'created',  'status')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])
            if tag_qs.exists():
                tag = tag_qs.first()
            else:
                tag = Tag.objects.get(**tag_data)
            instance.tag.add(tag)
        return movie
```

Views.py

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer
```

Error:

```
Traceback
    tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
KeyError: 'tag'
```

Comment: No, django is a framework on top of Python with a set structure of how to set up your models, urls, templates etc. Let's keep on topic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay.  I promised to come back when I figured it out. This probably isn't completely data-safe as django hasn't yet validated the incoming data so I'm making some assumptions in my relative ignorance of python and django.  If anyone who's smarter than I am can expand this answer, please hit me up.

*note: I am a firm adherent to the Clean Code standard of writing software.  It has served me well over the years.  I know it's not meta for Python code, but without small, tightly focused methods, it felt sloppy.*

**Views.py**

You have to clear the related objects yourself before you can add new ones if you can't have dupes.  It's the only way I could find to delete m2m reliably *for my use case*.  I needed to ensure there were no duplicates and I expect an atomic model.  Your mileage may vary.

```
class MovieViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def update(self, requiest, *args, **kwargs):
        movie = self.get_object()
        movie.tags.clear()
        return super().update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

You have to hook the `to_internal_value` serializer method to get the data you need since the validator ignores m2m fields.

```
class Tag1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name',)

class EditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = Tag1Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('title', 'tag', 'info', 'created',  'status')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        movie_id = data.get('id')
        #if it's new, we can safely assume there's no related objects.
        #you can skip this bit if you can't make that assumption.
        if self.check_is_new_movie(movie_id):
            return super().to_internal_value(data)
        #it's not new, handle relations and then let the default do its thing
        self.save_data(movie_id, data)
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    def check_is_new_movie(self, movie_id):
        return not movie_id

    def save_data(self, movie_id, data):
        movie = Movie.objects.filter(id=movie_id).first()
        #the data we have is raw json (string).  Listify converts it to python primitives.
        tags_data = Utils.listify(data.get('tags'))

        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])
            #I am also assuming that the tag already exists.  
            #If it doesn't, you have to handle that.
            if tag_qs.exists():
                tag = tag_qs.first()
                movie.tags.add(tag)
```

**Utils.py**

```
from types import *
class Utils:
#python treats strings as iterables; this utility casts a string as a list and ignores iterables
def listify(arg):
    if Utils.is_sequence(arg) and not isinstance(arg, dict):
        return arg
    return [arg,]

 def is_sequence(arg):
     if isinstance(arg, str):
         return False
     if hasattr(arg, "__iter__"):
         return True
```

**Test.py**

Adjust urls as necessary for this to work.  The logic should be correct but may need some tweaking to correctly reflect your models and serializers.  It's more complex because we have to create the json data for the APIClient to send with the put request.

```
class MovieAPITest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.url = '/movies/'

    def test_add_tag(self):
        movie = Movie.objects.create(name="add_tag_movie")
        tag = Tag.objects.create(name="add_tag")
        movie_id = str(movie.id)
        url = self.url + movie_id + '/'

        data = EditSerializer(movie).data
        data.update({'tags': Tag1Serializer(tag).data})
        json_data = json.dumps(data)

        self.client.put(url, json_data, content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(movie.tags.count(), 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

There's no `put` method on the drf model serializer class so nothing calls `put(self, validated_data)`. Use: `update(self, instance, validated_data)` instead. Docs on saving instances: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Also neither does the django model queryset has it: `Movie.objects.put` and `Tag.objects.put`. You have the `instance` argument for the movie already and if you are querying tags perhaps you need `Tag.objects.get` or `Tag.objects.filter`? QuerySet API Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api

After verifying that the serializer method is called, maybe you should write a test for it using drf test api client to be able to easily spot errors: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apiclient

serializers.py

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('name', 'taglevel', 'id')


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        ordering = ('-created',)
        fields = ('title', 'pk', 'tag')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop('tag')
        instance = super(MovieSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)

        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tag_qs = Tag.objects.filter(name__iexact=tag_data['name'])

            if tag_qs.exists():
                tag = tag_qs.first()
            else:
                tag = Tag.objects.create(**tag_data)

            instance.tag.add(tag)

        return instance
```

tests.py

```
class TestMovies(TestCase):
    def test_movies(self):
        movie = Movie.objects.create(title='original title')

        client = APIClient()
        response = client.put('/movies/{}/'.format(movie.id), {
            'title': 'TEST title',
            'tag': [
                {'name': 'Test item', 'taglevel': 1}
            ]
        }, format='json')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, response.content)
        # ...add more specific asserts
```

Comment: I've made those adjustments, but I now get the error "'int' object has no attribute 'tag'". Here is my tracback: http://dpaste.com/13CWNB2

Comment: so `movie` of `movie.tag.add(tag)` is an integer. `instance` is the movie you are editing so you can do `instance.tag.add(tag)`. or you can update your post with the latest code.

Comment: Still getting the same error with `instance.tag.add(tag)`. I've updated my post with the latest code

Comment: i included sample code in my answer since it's easier to explain the changes

Comment: Thanks, but that give me the error  `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: Your answer does not work. Could you please assist? I've updated my original answer, but it keeps returning a key error

Comment: Sure, you have to keep `read_only=False` on `TagSerializer` as it was originally but call `validated_data.pop('tag')` before calling super - as otherwise it will raise an error that you should handle nested fields manually. Also make sure your json is valid: `{"title": "TEST title", "tag": [{"name": "Test item", "taglevel": 1}]}`

Comment: So that tells me "Exception Value: Tag matching query does not exist.". Here's the trace http://dpaste.com/065PAX0

Comment: It's best if you compare the differences with the answer's code as it is a fully working example. In this case you probably want to use `Tag.objects.create` not `get`. In your code you first check with `filter` if a tag exists and if not you create a new tag.

Comment: If anyone in the future comes here as I did, this proposed answer does not work; the default validator for ModelSerializer does not handle m2m relationships.  @Ycon is getting that error because ('tag') doesn't exist in the key index for validated_data.  I believe a custom validator is required on the view.  I'll respond to this with a complete answer once I've figured it out.
Edit: source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#updating-nested-serializers